# jquery mobile listview with php not showing corectly

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I populate listview from mySQL and php, but when response text falls back in html, it shows like plain text, not listview. 
This is my html code:

```
<div data-role="page" id="myevents" data-theme="a">
<?php include("profileHeader.php");?>
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content" >
<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false"><h2>My events</h2>
<ul data-role="listview" id="myeventslist" data-inset="true">
</ul></div>
    </div>
```

This is script in html file:

```
<script>
$(document).on("pagecreate","#myevents",function(){
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("myeventslist").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "myeventslist.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send();

});
```

And this is my php script (myeventslist.php file):

```
//before this is PDO statement
    $myeventslist = '';
    foreach($stmtmyeventslist->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $myeventsrow){
        $myeventslist .= '<li>' . $myeventsrow['eventname'] . '</li>';

        }


$db=null; // Closing Connection

} catch (PDOException $e) {
//echo $e->getMessage();
echo "Error. Try again in 15 minutes";
die();
}

echo $myeventslist;
```

But results is not what i expected :( :
heh, i have no reputation level 10 to post picture

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. In html script block must contain:

```
$("#myeventslist").append(xmlhttp.responseText);
            $("#myeventslist").listview('refresh');
```

instead of:

```
document.getElementById("myeventslist").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
```